# CollectionView scroll to top

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, scroll, uicollectionview

I have one CollectionViewController and have 10 cells in it.

But when I run the app it displays the cell at bottom, but I want to display it from top cell at viewDidLoad.

I tried many things but it didn't work.

How to fix it?

Comment: please share your code..

Comment: I am using this, https://cocoapods.org/pods/SFFocusViewLayout. @PoojaSrivastava

Comment: @KAR Please share some code and screenshot of what type of collectionviewcell you want to get? Like what is problem ?

Comment: Are you working in Swift?

Comment: No, objective c. @Aisha

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add this line after reloading the collection view.

```
[self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

**Edit:**

Just want to add one more point here is if collectionView datasource has ZERO elements or it is `nil` then above code will not work and probably crash your app.

Write condition to check that datasource is available or not!

```
if (self.dataArray.count > 0) {
    [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
}
```

Where, `dataArray` is your datasource.

Comment: If you are feeling that this question will be helpful to others than upvote the question. @Aisha

Answer (score 40):

in swift 3: after reloadData()

```
  self.collectionView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:0,y:0), animated: true)
```

Comment: Works with Swift 4+ too

Answer (score 17):

Its work fine......

```
collectionView.setContentOffset(.zero, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 9):

Add this piece of code after reloading the collection view:

**swift**

`yourCollectionView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: true)`

**objective-c**

`[yourCollectionView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];`

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4 Swift 5**

Actually, it's work just do

```
collectionView.setContentOffset(.zero, animated: false)
```

But, if in case your CollectionView implement `.contentInset` or outer margin, let's say margin top & bottom is set `16`, this code will actually back to the top.

```
collectionView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -16), animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one

```
[self.yourcollectionview scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

Comment: where to add this line? @Monika patel

Comment: @KAR : Add this line after `[self.collectionview reloaddata];`

Comment: @KAR : Please up vote my answer. If my answer is useful to you

Comment: Please up vote the question so it will helpful to others.  @Monika Patel

Comment: no. view works fine before I rotate it 180. So after that it shows cell from bottom. I flip the view for change animation effect to opposite. @Monika Patel

Answer (score 0):

Make animated option false. Maybe some view animations are running during your collection view animation process.

```
collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: false)
```

Answer (score -10):

To display the data from top cell in collectionView you can use one method

```
[collectionView setScrollsToTop:YES];
```

Hope it will Help You.